# How do I access elements in jquery if the id is based on one of the function arguments?

Tags: javascript, jquery, element

I am trying to access an element in jquery using a function input.  To clarify, here is an example of what I have tried that isn't working:

```
function openReceivedMessage(messageid)
{
    // ajax post query that is executing fine

    // set row to not be highlighted
    var rowid = 'receivedrow' + messageid.toString();
    document.getElementById(rowid).style.background-color = "#ffffff";

    // other code that is executing fine
}
```

Essentially, this is for a message inbox page.  I have displayed the messages in a table, and, as the number of messages changes for each user, I used a loop to populate it.  In order to open a message, I have hoped to use a jquery function (titled above), and so when the loop populated the tables, I set it so that each of the different subject lines would, onclick, execute the above function with the unique messageid passed in as the argument. Upon opening, I want to change other things in the table (that I named, similar to the message function, as things like 'receivedrow#' where # is the messageid.

Would hugely appreciate any help here, I feel like there must be a simple way create a string (like I did with rowid above) and access the element with that id (in the table there is a row with id="receivedrow#" that I want to adjust the css of).

Comment: What doesn't work ? Did you try your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using jQuery to find the element

```
var rowid = 'receivedrow' + messageid.toString();
var $el = $("#" + rowid);
```

Then simply operate on $el

```
$el.css({'background-color':'#FFFFFF'});
```

If you're having trouble still, I recommend checking that rowid is correct and that the jQuery is then giving you the right element back.

Comment: Unfortunately no luck (I used the above verbatim and checked that 'receivedrow2' was indeed the id I was looking for.  Any other thoughts?  I have to imagine there's a relatively simple way to make this work

Comment: So you're saying $("#receivedrow2") didn't grab the element? Or that $el.css(...) didn't do anything?

Answer (score 1):

```
function openReceivedMessage(messageid)
{

   var rowid = 'receivedrow' + messageid.toString();
   var $el = $('#'+rowid);
   $el.css({'background-color':'#FFFFFF'});

// other code that is executing fine
}
```

Comment: I'm not getting it to work, would you mind showing me using the pieces from my example above?  I think I'm missing an apostrophe or something somewhere but can't find it.

Comment: Got it, some syntax that I left in like an idiot but now it's working.  Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Seems what you have posted is not jQuery at all :D

It is simple JavaScript trying to get a DOM element with id `rowid`. It does not works maybe be because of following two reasons:

1. there is no element with id `rowid` which you can easily verify.
2. `background-color` is not a property its `backgroundColor`.

Try using this:

```
document.getElementById(rowid).style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
```

Comment: Unfortunately no luck here (and I agree no jQuery in what's up there, was wondering if there's a way to do $('#xxxxx'), which sme of the others have suggested

Answer (score 0):

If you what you really need is an easy way get the id onclick, then simply use the *this* keyword in your row markup.

```
onclick="openReceivedMessage(this);"
```

Then access in your function as such:

```
function openReceivedMessage(row)
{    
    // set row to not be highlighted
    var rowid = 'receivedrow' + row.id;
    $('#' + rowid).css({'background-color':'#ffffff'});
}
```